# Calculate $\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{x^{2n}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration

For integer $n\ge0$, Calculate: $$\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{x^{2n}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\mathrm{d}x.$$

I would like to get suggestions on how to calculate it? Should I expand $(1-x^2)^{-1/2}$ as a series?

Thanks.

Comment: trigonometric substitution should work just fine for you

Comment: I am going in circle. I substitute $x=\sin\theta$ and now I get: $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\dfrac{\sin^{2n}\theta}{\cos\theta}\mathrm{d}\theta.$$

Comment: $dx=\cos\theta d\theta$

Comment: Thanks Aran. I get: $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{2n}\theta\mathrm{d}\theta.$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}{x^{2n} \over \root{1 - x^{2}}}\,\dd x&
=\int_{0}^{1}{x^{n} \over \root{1 - x}}\,\half\,x^{-1/2}\,\dd x
=\half\int_{0}^{1}x^{n - 1/2}\pars{1 - x}^{-1/2}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=\half\,{\Gamma\pars{n + 1/2}\Gamma\pars{1/2} \over \Gamma\pars{n + 1}}
={\root{\pi} \over 2\,n!}\,\Gamma\pars{n + \half}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$\ds{\Gamma\pars{z}}$ is the [Gamma Function](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_255.htm) ${\bf\mbox{6.1.1}}$.

> It's somehow related to [Wallis Formula](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_258.htm) ${\bf\mbox{6.1.49}}$ since
>   $$
> \int_{0}^{1}{x^{2n} \over \root{1 - x^{2}}}\,\dd x
> =\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{2n}\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta = {\pi \over 2^{2n + 1}}
> {2n \choose n}\tag{2}
> $$

$\pars{1}$ and $\pars{2}$ are related via
[Gamma Duplication Formula](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_256.htm)
${\bf\mbox{6.1.18}}$.

Answer (score 4):

Substitute $x=\sin{t}$. Then $t=\arcsin{x}$, $dt=\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$, and:

$$I(n)=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{x^{2n}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\mathrm{d}x = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{2n}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t.$$